# htaccess redirecting loop with browser

Tags: .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(gateway)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(inc)($|/) - [L]

# make sure it's not a directory or a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# match out the request URI without the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+?)/?$
# and see if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+?)\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index.php\?id=([a-z0-9]+)&num=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L,NC]

</ifModule>
```

Hi guys,
I have trouble with htaccess. It still warning by browser about This webpage has a redirect loop
I find more solution but i can't fix it :(
i tried to rewrite/redirect *.php to directory sample index.php to /index
And i want to rewrite url index.php?id=read&num=11233445667 to /read/11233445667

It worked. But still "This webpage has a redirect loop" :(

Please help me fix htaccess above. Im very thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the last rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index.php\?id=([a-z0-9]+)&num=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L,NC]
```

near the top (below `RewriteRule ^(inc)($|/) - [L]`)

so that it doesn't interfere with the more general php extension rules. You also probably should add conditions to the internal rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L,NC]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&num=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Dear, i found problem at my index.php file. because i set redirect when session timeout.So i replace it with session_destroy and it working fine. So your solution is still work fine. THank you :)